# Why my vue js data member is not getting updated?

Tags: vue.js

Data part

```
  data () {
    return {
      containsAd: true
    }
  },
```

Method that manipulates the data member `containsAd`

```
  updated () {
    let _this = this
    window.googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function (event) {
      if (event.slot.getSlotElementId() === 'div-gpt-ad-nativead1') {
        _this.containsAd = !event.isEmpty // this is false
        console.log('Ad Exists? ', _this.containsAd)
      }
    })
  },
```

Just to check if the value has changed or not.

```
check () {
  let _this = this
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('Current Value', _this.containsAd)
  }, 5000)
}
```

Resulting Output

[image]

Comment: You are adding event listener every time `data change causes the virtual DOM to be re-rendered`.
I think event listeners should be added in `mounted` or `created`

Comment: I was thinking too much that i thought of using update event. doing the same inside mounted worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think doing the event listener in the mounted hook will sort your issue.

```
data() {
    return {
        containsAd: true
    };
},

mounted() {
    window.googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', event => {
        if (event.slot.getSlotElementId() === 'div-gpt-ad-nativead1') {
            this.containsAd = ! event.isEmpty // this is false
            console.log('Ad Exists?', this.containsAd);
        }
    });
}
```

Also using es6 shorthand function will avoid you having to set `_this`.